# jquery Tree Traversal prev() in TD's

Tags: jquery, traversal

I'm trying to check/unckeck a selectbox by jquery in a previous TD. I have tried for hours several combination with prev(), parent(), closest(), but still without result... Here is the example code:

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" class="resultcheck"></td>
 <td><label class="resultchecklabel">Text 1</label></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" class="resultcheck"></td>
 <td><label class="resultchecklabel">Text 2</label></td>
 </tr>

</table>

<script>
$('.resultchecklabel').live('click', function() {
 if ($(this).prev('td input:checked').val() != null) 
 {
  $(this).prev('td').prev("input").removeAttr("checked");
 }
 else
 {
  $(this).prev('td').prev("input").attr("checked","checked");
 }
});
</script>
```

Who can help me to solve this question?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Adam and @peterendidit hit the nail on the head -- javascript/jQuery not needed here.

The reason that your code wasn't working though, is probably because `this` in your context is the `label` element, while the `td` are siblings of each other, not the `label`.  I think this would have done what you wanted and would suffice if you had more complicated requirements -- say additional styling, etc.

```
var cb = $(this).closest('td')  // containing TD
                .prev('td')     // previous TD
                .find('input'); // input within TD
if (cb.find(':checked').length == 0) { // not checked
    cb.attr('checked','checked');
}
else {
    cb.removeAttr('checked');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This gives me a better view in tree-traversal in jQuery and fixed my script! :-)

Answer (score 3):

#### real life solution

use `ID` in conjuction with `for`:

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" id="resultcheck1"></td>
 <td><label for="resultcheck1">Text 2</label></td>
```

and screw the javascript :]

#### Tree traversal:

You must think of it as a tree. that said, think about scope (what you have as $(this)):

Id you want to go from `resultchecklabel` to `resultcheck`, you have to go up to `td`=>previous `td`=>it's child `resultcheck`.

Translated to tree relations: `parent`=>`previous sibling`=>`child`. now, it's easy to translate this english to jQuery, since it's really straightforward:

```
var $dest = $(this).parent('td').prev().children('.resultcheck')
```

As you see, when you think in intensions of movement on the tree, it's pretty much english with parentheses.

#### example:

http://jsbin.com/evupu/2

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution is very common to me, but my qwestion was pointed to tree-traversel in jquery.

Comment: @Guido: Answered. Next time please, clarify, that it's for learning/testing/playing purposes, because in real life, I strongly advise you to use `id`/`for` in favor of this.

Answer (score 2):

Labels don't need fancy javascript to be connected to input elements.  Just give the input an ID and use the for attribute on the label:

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" class="resultcheck" id="resultcheck1"></td>
 <td><label class="resultchecklabel" for="resultcheck1">Text 1</label></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" class="resultcheck" id="resultcheck2"></td>
 <td><label class="resultchecklabel" for="resultcheck2">Text 2</label></td>
 </tr>

</table>
```